# Back button on google maps ios

Tags: ios, google-maps

My Iphone app needs to open the google maps application to use the StreetView and the directions mode.

All works fine,But my question is, is there any way of adding a button or something to go back to my app?. I have seen that with UIWebViews maybe thats the only solution..

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you open the app btw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer comes from this documentation: [Google Maps SDK for iOS, Google Maps URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=GM-for-iOS-sdk-1-7#add_a_back_button_to_google_maps_for_ios)

You may add a back button if you register a custom URL scheme for your app and use the `comgooglemaps-x-callback://` url scheme to launch the Google Maps iOS app.

Here is a great [tutorial for iOS Custom URL Schemes](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

The following string would open Google Maps with directions to JFK airport and would add a button in Google Maps with the title "AirApp".
Touching that button would call the custom url scheme `sourceapp://` which you would set up by following the tutorial I linked to above.

```
@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://?daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=AirApp"
```

Comment: The App I was developing when I had this problem is already finished, but I am sure I will use the callback stuff on future apps. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Great! You should mark my answer as correct for the sake of anyone who finds this question in the future.

Comment: Hi, I am following the above code, but I am not able to see the "AirApp" button when google maps open. I am using iOS 11.3.1. Please anyone can help me with this?